# How to trigger a goal programmatically out of web request?

Tags: xdb, goals

When I am importing contacts (within a scheduled job, which is our of request) I want to check few business conditions and if contact matches the condition, I want to trigger a goal for the contact.

The goal will execute rule action on enrolling the contact in the engagement flow.

Is that possible and how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goal registration heavily relies on the current session. I am not aware of a good way to properly register a goal outside of actual session, page, and request being available.

To enroll a contact into a specific state in an engagement plan, you can try using this API:

```
using Sitecore.Analytics.Automation;

// ...

bool success = AutomationContactManager.AddContact(
    contactId,
    automationStateId,
    new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

This method will return false in the following cases:

- The contact with given ID does not exist;
- The database is unavailable;
- The contact is locked by another process;
- The contact is already in the given state;
- The given automation state does not exist;
- An exception occurs (it will be logged).

To check if a contact is already enrolled in a certain plan, you can use the following code:

```
Contact contact = ...
var manager = AutomationStateManager.Create(contact);
bool isInPlan = manager.IsInEngagementPlan(planId);
```

Comment: What is supposed to go into customData dictionary?
the new Dictionary<string, object>()?

Comment: You don't have to pass anything—that dictionary is for custom values. It's mainly used by EXM states, I believe.

Comment: I also need to check whether this contact is already in this engagement flow (not necessarily in given state). If it is I should not enroll. I can't find a static  method in AutomationContactManager  for that...

Comment: @VolodymyrHil I have updated my answer to include that information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this and let you know the results..